# Pesquisa mysql com saltos de horas/dias/mês

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Gostaria de entender como posso fazer uma pesquisa no mysql pulando uma determinada quantidades de dias de cada resgistro, por exemplo, mostrar os registros do inicio de uma tabela até o fim pulando de 7 em 7 dias, ou de 1 em 1 mês.
Já fiz algo semelhante más limitado, segue o código abaixo:

```
SELECT `id`,`cod`,`corrente`,MIN(`data_hora`) as `data_hora` FROM sensores WHERE `cod` LIKE '001' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`data_hora`, '%Y%m%d%H') ORDER BY `sensores`.`id` ASC
```

Esse código pulas os registros de 1 em 1 hora, segue outros exemplos:

```
        Intervalos por minuto = ... GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`data_hora`, '%Y%m%d%H%i')
        Intervalos por hora = ... GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`data_hora`, '%Y%m%d%H')
        Intervalos por dia = ... GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`data_hora`, '%Y%m%d')
```

É eficiente mas gostaria de mais opções de intervalos, como 30 minutos, 7, 15 ou 20 dias.

Preciso disso pois tenho um grande numero de registros em um banco e acaba ficando muito pesado para passar tudo isso para um gráfico.

Comment: Você quer agrupar por períodos, isso? Qual a sua versão do MySQL?

Comment: Já tentou? `group by DAY(campo_data) ,WEEK(campo_data), MONTH(campo_data), YEAR(campo_data)`, e `DATE_ADD(campo_data, INTERVAL 10 DAY);` ou `DATE_ADD(campo_data, INTERVAL 15 MINUTE);`

Comment: A versão do mysql é a 15.1

Comment: Tentei, más ele me mostra um resultado de cada dia independente do valore em (campo_data, INTERVAL 15 MINUTE);

Comment: Tente criar uma procedure para isso.